# i am trying to make JButton Age calculate but I Have errors

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package project;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class agecal {
    
    JButton MyButton = new JButton("This is my button.");
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    MyButton.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void buttonFunction (Action Event e){
    int age;
    age = currentYear - birthYear;
    textField.setText(age);
    }}
```

How do I make this JButton shown below when someone types birth year it shows age image below [JButton Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhY0J.png)

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are trying to print an int on `setText()` method, this method accept a String as a parameter use

```
textField.setText(String.valueOf(age));
```